# how to check is staff is True before login into dashboard which i have created by myself in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, view, django-views

I have created a dashboard and in my dashboard superuser creates the username, password, and all this thing but in my dashboard, I want to check first the username is staff or not before login into the dashboard. how to do that? can anyone help me

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib import auth, messages
from orderkitchen.models import kitchenData 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def login_dashboard(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            messages.success(request, 'You are Logged in')
            return redirect('dashboard')
            
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Your Username or Password is incorrect')
            return redirect('login_dashboard')
        return
    else:
        return render(request,'accounts/dashboard_login.html')

def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html')
```

only the staff status is True then only then can logged in

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `status` after `authenticate` if it returns not `None` as

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib import auth, messages
from orderkitchen.models import kitchenData 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def login_dashboard(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if user is not None and user.is_staff == True:
            auth.login(request,user)
            messages.success(request, 'You are Logged in')
            return redirect('dashboard')
        
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Your Username or Password is incorrect')
            return redirect('login_dashboard')
        return
    else:
        return render(request,'accounts/dashboard_login.html')

def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you authenticate a user, you get the User object through which you can access the is_staff field from the AUTH_MODEL.

```
user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)
if user is not None:
    if user.is_staff:
        auth.login(request,user)
        messages.success(request, 'You are Logged in')
        return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        # user is not staff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in views.py:

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    if request.user.is_staff == True:
        return render(request, 'dashboard.html')
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

This method uses Django authentication wrapper first to make sure the user is logged-in.

You could also add the following to the `dashboard.html` file:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
{% if request.user.is_staff %}
<div>
<p>Welcome to your Dashboard <b>{{request.user.email}}</b></p>
</div>
{% else %}
<!-- Show HTML content to other users here -->
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```